# Meteor subscription in router

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

My goal is to publish user data of 3 users on the client side on the router path /home2.

Code is as below:

```
Meteor.publish "featured_talent", ->
    console.log 'talent publishing:'
    query = 
        'profile.picture':
            $exists: true
            $ne: null
        'show_on_talent_view': true
        'profile.roles.talent': true

    options = 
        limit: 3
        fields:
            profile: 1
        sort:
            createdAt: -1
    usr = Meteor.users.find query, options
    return usr
```

subscribing in router on server

```
Router.map ->
    @route "home2",
        path: "/home2"
        waitOn: ->
            Meteor.subscribe "featured_talent"
```

I am not able to get the data on the client side, that is my publication is not working!

Comment: Well, obviously the variable `query` is not available in your `server/router.coffee`. If you want to define a global variable, don't use `var` or in your case, use `@query = …`.

Comment: so in my publish i used @query = 
    'profile.picture':
        $exists: true
        $ne: null 

    'profile.is_test':
        $ne: true

    'profile.is_featured': true

    'profile.roles.talent': true

Still same error!

Comment: I am new to meteor, so if u can elaborate a little more, it would b a big favor! thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a repository?

Comment: Well than its gonna be a trouble, the repo is private. I am interning at a company and surely dunno if thats allowed.

Comment: Then just create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yes I can do that Sir!

Comment: the problem isn't in the publication. it's a problem in the router

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock can you elaborate?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer. What is the variable 'query'?

Comment: well I got rid of this error by removing     data: users: Meteor.users.find query, options

My goal is to publish this data on client.

I will make changes in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query` on the following line in your router isn't defined:

```
users: Meteor.users.find query, options
```